# Creating custom annotations with place-holder?

Tags: java, parsing, annotations, placeholder

I'm creating some custom annotations. I need to create someones with "place-holders" as it is used in Spring

```
@Value("#{aParameter}")
```

or in JSF 2

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{aParameter}")
```

I suppose that I must have a mapping somewhere (.properties  or .xml file or an enum class) but I need to know to code this approach in custom annotation interface. I mean how to declare a place-holder in the annoatation interface ? and how to ensure the assignement of its value (in mapping file) when applying the annotation somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do it in the annotation declaration - you do it in the code using that annotation.

For example the `@Value` is declared like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Value {

    /**
    * The actual value expression: e.g. "#{systemProperties.myProp}".
    */
    String value();
}
```

and if you trace how it's used you'll see that in `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker` class the value is fetched directly from the annotation `defaultValue = ((Value) paramAnn).value();` and then resolved like this:

```
if (defaultValue != null) {
    args[i] = resolveDefaultValue(defaultValue);
}

...
class AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter{
...
protected Object resolveDefaultValue(String value) {
    if (beanFactory == null) {
        return value;
    }    
    String placeholdersResolved = beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(value);
    BeanExpressionResolver exprResolver = beanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver();
    if (exprResolver == null) {
        return value;
    }
    return exprResolver.evaluate(placeholdersResolved, expressionContext);
}
```

So the logic taking care of resolving properties and such is placed in classes
that actually use read annotations and make them useful.